# Is it possible to repeat a captured group in the substitution in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, perl, substitution, capturing-group

Is it possible with regex to repeat a captured group an amount of times with the added restriction that the amount to repeat is also found in a capture group?

Example:

```
Regex: /(a)([0-9])/g
String: ba1na3na2
Expected result: banaaanaa
```

I have never seen anything that does this, but maybe I have been looking in the wrong places. Note: I am using Perl - but I am interested to see answers for other flavours as well.

Comment: did you hear above `e` modifier?

Comment: How do you want the regex itself to do that -- how would you use it? The `m/` just returns matches, I think.  In the `s/`? That changes the string, is that OK?

Comment: I love the example data! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In perl this regular expression will give you the expected result, your regexp is a match, while the `s` regular expression is a substitution:

```
s/(a)([0-9])/$1 x $2/eg;
```

Like this:

```
my $str = 'ba1na3na2';
$str =~ s/(a)([0-9])/$1 x $2/eg;
print $str;
```

> banaaanaa

- The `e` modifier evaluates the right-hand side as an expression.
- The `x` operator repeates the string.

**Update:**

As @AvinashRaj says it might be `s/(a)([0-9]+)/$1 x $2/eg;` is more approriate. Depending on if you want
`ba20nana` to become

- baa0nana

or

- baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanana

Comment: this `s/(a)([0-9]+)/$1 x $2/eg;` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes. Depending on OP's requirements.

Comment: I am saving these nasty regex tricks, do you guys realize that?  Is that OK? :)